# The Composition Time(CTS) when wrapping H.264 NALU's

Tags: h.264, flv, mpeg-4

The h.264 hardware compression card procedures NALU's from captured video.

I am trying to wrap the NALU's into FLV and I almost succeed.

I don't know how to fill the Composition Time field in FLV for each NALU.

According to the FLV spec, http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf, E.4.3.1.

> **CompositionTime**  Composition time offset
>
> See ISO 14496-12, 8.15.3 for an explanation of composition  times. The
> offset in an FLV file is always in milliseconds

Then look into the [ISO 14496-12,8.15.3](http://xcshen.blog.51cto.com/attachment/201104/2835389_1302074539.pdf) , Page 24 and 26

> provides the offset between decoding time and composition
> time. Since decoding time must be less  than the composition time, the
> offsets are expressed as unsigned numbers such that  **CT(n) = DT(n) +**
> **CTTS(n) where CTTS(n)** is the (uncompressed) table entry for sample n.

How can I know the DT and CTTS in each NALU? or how to caculate the CT without DT and CTTS?

Thank you

Comment: When storing video stream with B-Frames, PTS (Presentation timestamp) may be larger than DTS (Decoder timestamp). It happens because b-frame requires frames following after it do be decoded.

Answer (score 11):

For MPEG-4 H.264 transcoders that deliver I-frame, P-frame, and B-frame NALUs inside an MPEG-2 transport, the resulting packetized elementary streams (PES) are timestamped with presentation time stamps (PTS) and decoder timestamps (DTS) in time units of 1/90000 of a second.

The NALUs come in DTS timestamp order in a repeating pattern like

```
I P B B B P B B B ...
```

where the intended playback rendering is

```
I B B B P B B B P ...
```

(This transport strategy ensures that both frames that the B-frame bridges are in the decoder before the B-frame is processed.)

For FLV, the Timestamp (FLV spec p.69) tells when the frame should be fed to the decoder in milliseconds, which is

```
timestamp = DTS / 90.0
```

The CompositionTime (FLV spec p.72) tells the renderer when to perform ("compose") the video frame on the display device in milliseconds after it enters the decoder; thus it is

```
compositionTime = (PTS - DTS) / 90.0
```

(Because the PTS >= DTS, this delta is never negative.)

Comment: How can we calculate the DTS of a frame in NAL stream?

Comment: Both PTS and DTS are encoded in the PES packet as defined in Table 2-21 of ISO 13818-1 (MPEG-2 specification).

Comment: The `compositionTime` is `unsigned int` in MP4 but `signed int` in FLV. And it is possible the PTS <= DTS in FLV.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have understood the CTS.  it is only for B-frames.
Because B-frames may depends fowarding frames to decode, so the CTS means when this B-frame can be decoded, usually that means all the depended frames are received.

Comment: What about frame type? Are you also setting the frame type to 2 while streaming B frames?